# Assert calls segmentation fault

Tags: c, assert

I'd written some sort of basic multi-threading library. So, for each thread, I'd a context (`ucontext_t`). In one of my test programs, I put an assert which failed. Instead of aborting with a line number, it threw a segmentation fault. I then checked and saw the stack size of my context was 8192. When I increased it to 16394, the assert failure worked as expected.

Can you someone tell me as to how assert works internally and why would it use up so many bytes? I believe 8192 is a fairly large size for my context.

This is how my thread is created

```
MyThread *temp;
temp=malloc(sizeof(MyThread_t));
ucontext_t tempContext;
if (getcontext(&tempContext) == -1)
  temp->ThreadId = 0;
tempContext.uc_stack.ss_sp = (char *)malloc(SIZE_STACK*sizeof(char));;
tempContext.uc_stack.ss_size = SIZE_STACK*sizeof(char);
tempContext.uc_link = NULL;
makecontext(&tempContext,(void(*)(void))start_funct,1, args);
```

And my test function has it this way.

```
T = MyThreadCreate(t0, (void *)n2);
re=MyThreadJoin(T);
printf("%d\n",re);
assert(re==-1);
```

re value is 0. When my SIZE_STACK is 8192, I get a seg fault. When its increased to 16384, it is a proper abort as expected from assert.

Comment: You could use a tool like `valgrind` to get some more insight in what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of assert is platform dependent.

Comment: Any idea as to why it would need such a large space? In my case, my thread contains only a few variables. So, I believe the stack is mostly empty..

Comment: What compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: gcc. Running it on Ubuntu 13.04 which is running on a Virtual Box on Win 8.

Comment: Do you mean platform and compiler dependent? i just get stuck for 2 days because of that, on a Linux grid computing it generate SegFault, but on my linux machine, i get an error message, anyway i was asking myself the same question, and here i am, thank you !!!

Comment: @HanniBaL90 Yes, OS and compiler dependent. Perhaps even hardware dependent, although I cannot think of an example right now. I was using "platform" more broadly than just the OS.